# How to overcome 10 sec serverless limitation timeout in Vercel?

Tags: node.js, timeout, serverless, vercel, animated-gif

Our React / Next.js web app has an animation rendering part. We does image rendering, generating GIF / MP4 with Vercel serverless solution.

But typically operation does not finish in 10sec. Sometimes it is 15 sec.

What can I do? I have two ideas.

1. Run cron job in every 5 sec. It checks is it any rendering not yet executed, if so, then process it.

https://vercel.com/guides/what-can-i-do-about-vercel-serverless-functions-timing-out

Does cron job has same timeout? In Heroku not.

2. Do rendering not on Vercel, but make a Node.js app, and run on Heroku, where same timeout is 15sec, and it can even increase to 45 sec.

What is your opionion?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Vercel pro or above, you can export a `maxDuration` variable in your API route to increase the timeout to up to 5 minutes

See https://vercel.com/changelog/serverless-functions-can-now-run-up-to-5-minutes

```
// someAPI.ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

// for app router
export const maxDuration = 30;

// for pages router
export const config = {
maxDuration: 30,
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
// ...etc
```